# How to load a .json file as a dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to save the information from a .json file as a dictionary containing other dictionaries. I attempted, but, when I try to access the first key, it is a string, rather than another dictionary. Here is my code:

```
with open('matches1.json', 'r') as json_file:
    match_histories = json.load(json_file)
print(match_histories[key]['matches'])
for i in range(6):
    print(match_histories[key][i])
```

The first print results in an error, the second results in 'matches'.

The file I want to load can be [downloaded](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/riot-api/seed_data/matches1.json) but the structure is basically:

```js
{
    "matches": [
        {
            "matchId": 1778839570,
            "region": "NA",
            "platformId": "NA1",
            "matchMode": "CLASSIC",
            "matchType": "MATCHED_GAME",
            "matchCreation": 1427867835805,
            "matchDuration": 3424,
            "queueType": "RANKED_SOLO_5x5",
            "mapId": 11,
            "season": "SEASON2015",
            "matchVersion": "5.6.0.194",
            "participants": [
                // more dictionaries
                ],
            "participantIdentities": [
                // more dictionaries
            ],
            "teams": [
                // more dictionaries
            ],
            "timeline": {
                "frames": [
                    // many frame dictionaries
                ],
                "frameInterval": 60000
            }
        },

        // more dictionaries
    ]
}
```

I saved it as matches1.json in the same directory as my code.

I have also tried putting

```
match_histories={}
```

before my other code, but that didn't help either.

How can I save this .json file as a dictionary containing dictionaries?

Comment: Also, please reduce this to a *small sample*, not a 18MB file that needs to be downloaded separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`match_histories` is a dictionary with *one* key, `matches`. The value is a list of dictionaries; loop over that list:

```
for match in match_histories['matches']:
    print(match['matchId'])
```

Warning: the `match` objects are themselves *large* dictionaries.